# How can I change my python version in git bash?

Tags: python, bash, git

I been looking at fixes for this but im terrible at search. I came across this fix

didnt work

```
$ PATH=$PATH:/c/Python36/python
$ python --version
Python 2.7.13
```

I came across an alias fix turned out to be temporary so that didnt work

I want basically every command i do like everything under Python36/Scripts like pip, pytest, etc to be from python36. But everything is going to python 2.7

how do you change your python version? I am trying to change my git bash python version from python 2.7.13 to 3.6. I don't want to delete python 2.7 tho

Comment: Try this : `PATH=/c/Python36/python:$PATH` if you want both like `python3` and `python` try copy and paste the python3 exe and rename it to python3, and your way of $PATH will work.

Comment: Didn't work, still shows 2.7.13 when i do version after that

Comment: ohhh, i realized why its under an alias https://gyazo.com/67a099b465f0cf404b8cc80e64fa71c8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
pkg install python2
```

And to use python2 do

```
python2 yourcode.py
```

And for python3 use

```
python3 yourcode.py
```

To check Version if you check:

```
python - -version
```

It will give 3.9.2 for me and 3.6 for you but if you check

```
python2 - - version
```

It will give the result 2.7.18

Here is the proof:
[image: Proof]

Answer (score 0):

Check this in order to change the default python version without removing the package.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/521060/214441